# Rails :OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, ubuntu-18.04

I have ROR application deployed on multiple EC2 instances in production, some are on **Ubuntu
14.04.5 LTS** and some on **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS**.

On servers with **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS** once in while the application gets an error while connecting to any **S3 (though practically any https URL)** and no issues on servers with Ubuntu 14,

```
Error Occurred: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

After **restart** it gets resolved without any code change or fix.

On further investigation we see one more diff on the env. servers **with** this error-

```
OpenSSL=OpenSSL 1.1.1
```

servers **without** any error-

```
OpenSSL version=1.0.1f
```

I have found a [link](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2415#issuecomment-517680905) here where users are complaining same problem and getting resolved after restart.

So, question--
1.How this issue can be resolved, someone has faced the same or similar problem?
2.What things changes after the restart that application start working fine with same code?
Please help me, looking for some guidance.

Comment: You should look for an issue in openssl repo/bug tracker. Most likely an upgrade or a downgrade of openssl would resolve it.

Comment: Thank you for direction, will see, though, we have been struggling on this for almost a month, explored all the options, hence trying to see if can get some help on SO,